# В проверке выдает ошибку(CodeWars).Как исправить?

Tags: c#

Код прошел тест, но не прошел финальный тест. В чем проблема? На фото видно и код и задание + код ниже.

Задание:

> In a small town the population is p0 = 1000 at the beginning of a year. The population regularly increases by 2 percent per year and moreover 50 new inhabitants per year come to live in the town. How many years does the town need to see its population greater or equal to p = 1200 inhabitants?
>
> - At the end of the first year there will be:
>   1000 + 1000 * 0.02 + 50 => 1070 inhabitants
> - At the end of the 2nd year there will be:
>   1070 + 1070 * 0.02 + 50 => 1141 inhabitants (number of inhabitants is an integer)
> - At the end of the 3rd year there will be:
>   1141 + 1141 * 0.02 + 50 => 1213
>
> It will need 3 entire years.
> More generally given parameters:
>
> - p0, percent, aug (inhabitants coming or leaving each year), p (population to surpass)
> - the function nb_year should return n number of entire years needed to get a population greater or equal to p.
> - aug is an integer, percent a positive or null number, p0 and p are positive integers (> 0)
>
> Examples:
> nb_year(1500, 5, 100, 5000) -> 15
> nb_year(1500000, 2.5, 10000, 2000000) -> 10
>
> Note: Don't forget to convert the percent parameter as a percentage in the body of your function: if the parameter percent is 2 you have to convert it to 0.02.

```
class Arge
{

    public static int NbYear(int p0, double percent, int aug, int p)
    {
        int years = 0;
        while(p0 <= p)
        {
            years++;
            p0 = Convert.ToInt32(p0 + (p0 * (percent / 100)) + aug);
        }
        return years;
    }
}
```

[image: Задание и код]

Comment: Будьте добры, приведите и задание, и ваш код, и проваленные тесты текстом.

Comment: @tym32167 извиняюсь

Comment: Вы добавили просто ссылку на задание. Она может устареть и перестать быть акутальной - и ваш вопрос станет непонятным ни для кого. Вот если добавить текст задания в вопрос, то он даже начнет индексироваться поисковиками и всё, кто будут искать тут подобный вопрос его легко найдут.

Comment: Я вам написал ответ, надеюсь вы отплатите тем же и приведете в порядок вопрос.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо огромное,просто в вопросе сказано больше или равен,а не просто больше.

Comment: вот именно, если больше или равен - то закончить цикл. Если меньше - то продолжать. А у вас "меньше или равен" в вашем коде, что противоречит заданию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, что у вас проблема тут `while(p0 <= p)` так как если `p0 == p` то ждать ещё год не надо.

Вот решение, что у меня получилось

```
public static int NbYear(int p0, double percent, int aug, int p) {
    int years = 0; 
    while(p0<p){
       p0 = p0 + aug + (int)(p0*percent/100);
       years ++;
    }
    return years;
}
```